# Show that: $\sin ^2 (a+b)+\sin ^2 (a-b)=4(1-\cos ^2 a \cos ^2 b)$

Tags: trigonometry

Show that: $$\sin ^2 (a+b)+\sin ^2 (a-b)=4(1-\cos ^2 a \cos ^2 b)$$

I tried two approaches.

Approach 1: $$\sin ^2 (a \pm b)=\sin a\cos b \pm \sin b\cos a$$

This reduced to: $$2(\cos ^2 a +\cos ^2 b -2\cos ^2 a\cos ^2b)$$

I can't see where to go from here.

Approach 2: $$\sin ^2 (a \pm b)=1-\cos ^2 (a \pm b)$$

This reduced to: $$2(\cos ^2 a +\cos ^2 b -2\cos ^2 a\cos ^2b)$$

Both approaches reduced to the same expression which is a good sign, but I still can't figure out how to make the final manipulation.

Comment: What if $a=b=\pi/2$? What do the two sides reduce to then?

Comment: Set $b=0$ and the equation you are supposed to prove is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=30°,b=60°$

LHS=$\frac{5}{4}$

RHS=$\frac{13}{4}$

LHS$\ne $ RHS

Hence question is wrong

Comment: In fact, the LHS is equal to $$2(\cos^2 a + \cos^2 b) - 4\cos^2 a \cos^2 b$$ which is different than right side's $$1- 4\cos^2 a \cos^2 b$$

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that
$$1-\cos(2a+2b)+1-\cos(2a-2b)=2(4-(1+\cos2a)(1+\cos2b))$$ or
$$2-2\cos2a\cos2b=2(3-\cos2a-\cos2b-\cos2a\cos2b)$$ or
$$\cos2a+\cos2b=2,$$
which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

hint:$$\sin ^2 (a+b)+\sin ^2 (a-b)=4(1-\cos ^2 a \cos ^2 b)=\\1-\cos(2a+2b)+1-\cos(2a-2b)=\\2-(\cos(2a+2b)+\cos(2a-2b))= $$use sum to product formula

$$=2-(\cos(2a+2b)+\cos(2a-2b))=\\2 -2\cos (\frac{2a+2b+2a-2b}{2}).\cos (\frac{2a+2b-(2a-2b)}{2})=\\2-2\cos (2a).\cos (2b)=\\$$

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\sin ^2 (a+b)+\sin ^2 (a-b)=[\sin (a+b)+\sin (a-b)]^2-2\sin(a+b)\cdot\sin(a-b)$$

Now use that sum-product relations:

$$\sin (a+b)+\sin (a-b)=2\sin (a)\cos (b)$$

$$2\sin(a+b)\cdot\sin(a-b)=\cos(2b)-\cos(2a)=2(\cos^2(b)-\cos^2(a))$$

So,

$$S=4(1-\cos^2(a))\cos^2(b)+2\cos^2(a)-2\cos^2(b)$$

$$S=4(1-\cos^2(a))\cos^2(b)+2\cos^2(a)-2\cos^2(b)$$

$$S=2[\cos^2(a)+\cos^2(b)]-4\cos^2(a)\cos^2(b)$$

and then the statement is wrong.